# Fill holes in FRED data in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my name is Nick and I am new to coding. I recently completed Codeacademy's Analyze Financial Data with Python course. I've started working on some projects of my own, and I've run into a road block.

I'm importing stock index daily closing price data from the Federal Reserve API (FRED) using pandas-datareader:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime(2020, 1, 1)

sp_data = web.DataReader('SP500', 'fred', start)
```

The dataframe `sp_data` is formatted like so:

```
              SP500
DATE               
2020-01-01      NaN
2020-01-02  3257.85
2020-01-03  3234.85
2020-01-06  3246.28
2020-01-07  3237.18
```

The problem with this dataframe is that on days when the markets are closed (weekends, holidays), those dates are completely omitted. You can see above that 2020-01-04 and 2020-01-05 are missing because they are weekends. I would like my dataframe to have all dates, even when the market is closed. On dates when the markets are closed, I would like the SP500 column to just have the most recent closing price. So on 2020-01-04 and 2020-01-05, the SP500 column would have 3234.85.

I've tried to create a new dataframe with every date I need:

```
date_list = pd.date_range(start, np.datetime64('today'))
df = pd.DataFrame(date_list)
df.columns =['date']
```

This creates:

```
        date
0 2020-01-01
1 2020-01-02
2 2020-01-03
3 2020-01-04
4 2020-01-05
```

I'm now trying to create an 'SP500' column in `df` by iterating through each row in `sp_data` and if the dates match, it assigns that value to that date in `df`. I will then use `pd.DataFrame.ffill` to fill the missing values. The lambda function I am using to create the new column is:

```
df['SP500'] = sp_data.apply(lambda row: row['SP500'] if row.index == df.date else 0, axis=1)
```

This returns:

```
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

I know that the dataframes need to be the same length to use a lambda function on. I guess my question is, what is the best way to iterate over each row in a Pandas dataframe to assign the proper values to the correct dates in the new dataframe? Are there any ways to accomplish the same end goal that are much easier than the way I am trying to tackle it?

Any and all suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what indexes are use for, if there is a match between the index int new empty dataframe (`df`), and the dataframe with the data (`sp_data`), then the value will be added to the new dataframe, else it will asign NaN values. Your `df` should be an empty dataframe with index `date_list` and after that, just assign the new column:

```
date_list = pd.date_range(start, np.datetime64('today'))
df = pd.DataFrame(index=date_list)

df['SP500'] = sp_data['SP500']
```